# Como inserir um serialize no banco em um campo do tipo string

Tags: php, laravel

Galera, tenho uma aplicação **Laravel** e estou precisando inserir um valor que esta passando primeiramente por um `serealize()` no PHP em meu banco em um campo *string*.

Este é o *array*

```
$dia_semana = array(serialize($request->dia_semana));

dd($dia_semana);
```

Este é o resultado:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "a:3:{i:0;s:1:"0";i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;s:1:"2";}"
]
```

Preciso que seja inserido no campo "***dia_semana*** (string/varchar)" no banco da seguinte forma `0, 1, 2, 3` sendo 0- segunda, 1- terca, 2- quarta e assim por diante. Este campo é um checkbox em minha aplicação ele podendo marcar 1 ou vários dias.

Primeiramente não sei ao certo se precisava do `array()` antes do serialize.

Se eu remover meu `dd()` o código cai em meu `catch()` retornando

> Array to string conversion

Creio que justamente pelo problema acima pois o *array* não foi tratado.

Comment: Pense comigo, se quer salvar uma string, por que criar um array?

Comment: opa, bom dia anderson, ele ja cria um array pelo serialize brother, preciso digamos, transformar este array do serialize  em "0,1,2".

Comment: Como assim cria o array pelo serialize? Não é pelo `array()` que você cria o array?

Comment: o que eu quis dizer é que com o ```array()``` ou nao ele ja se torna um "***array***" pelo serealize

Comment: Isso não faz sentido. Pela própria [documentação a própria função `serialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php) retorna uma *string*.

Comment: Aliás, por que está serializando o seu objeto? Se `$request->dia_semana` é um *array*, então não bastaria fazer `join(', ', $request->dia_semana)`?

Comment: opa, ja consegui aqui o que eu queria, fiz o que o amigo jorge abaixo disse utilizando ```$casts``` e depois utilizei o implode  ```$dia = implode(',', $request->dia_semana);``` o resultado foi o que eu esperava "1,2,3", obrigado de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça uso do que o Laravel oferece, no caso *atribute casting*.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

O Laravel faz o serialize, unserialize automaticamente.

No seu Model

```
protected $casts = [
        'dias_semana' => 'array',
    ];
```

Comment: obrigado jorge pela ajuda, utilizei o $casts e depois utilizei o implode $dia = implode(',', $request->dia_semana); o resultado foi o que eu esperava "1,2,3", obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

Eu usaria uma column do tipo json, mysql e postgresql já permitem por exemplo, passar um json_encode com  informação desejada para salvar nessa coluna, e usaria o $cast como o amigo disse.

A vantagem de usar o tipo json no banco é que vc conseguirá pesquisar dentro de um objeto json sem problemas =D